# Read terminal argument and pass the function in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

```
(defun gppinterpreter (filename)
    (setq fileContent (read-a-file filename))
    (write filecontent)
)
(gppinterpreter filename)
```

I compile this file in ubuntu

clisp example.lisp

I want to get the filename parameter directly from the terminal such as >> clisp example.lisp filename

but this command not working. How can I get filename parameter in gppinterpreter from terminal

Comment: `fileContent` is an undefined variable. That's a mistake in Lisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Clisp, the program arguments are given in the variable `EXT:*ARGS*.`.

https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/clisp.html

> Before it is loaded, the variable EXT:*ARGS* is bound to a LIST of STRINGs, representing the arguments given to the Lisp script (i.e., $1 in /bin/sh becomes (FIRST EXT:*ARGS*) etc).

So I think you want to use `(second EXT:*ARGS*)`